# Plotting pcolormesh from filtered pandas dataframe for defined x/y ranges, even if that row or column doesn't exist in the filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've loaded some data into a pandas dataframe that has multiples records.  Each record has an hour and weekday value.  I'm pivoting these into a 2D matrix to plot with pyplot.pcolormesh.  The problem is when I filter the table, I get 2D matrices which do not have any values for entire columns/rows in my output.  How can I force pcolormesh to respect an xrange/yrange and fill those cells with either zeros or nodata values?

```
def timeHeatmap(data):
    for group in data.GroupID.unique():
        data_daytime = pd.pivot_table(data[data['GroupID'] == group], index='Weekday', columns='Hour', values='Value', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
        data_daytime = data_daytime.fillna(0)

        # Plot it out
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        plt.axis([0, 24, 0, 7])
        heatmap = ax.pcolormesh(data_daytime, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha=1)
        plt.colorbar(mappable=heatmap, orientation='horizontal', label='Number of Crashes')

        # Format
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.set_size_inches(11, 8)

        # turn off the frame
        ax.set_frame_on(False)

        # put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
        ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data_daytime.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data_daytime.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)

        # want a more natural, table-like display
        ax.invert_yaxis()
        ax.xaxis.tick_top()

        # Set the labels
        xlabels = ['12a','1a','2a','3a','4a','5a','6a','7a','8a','9a','10a','11a','12p','1p','2p','3p','4p','5p','6p','7p','8p','9p','10p','11p']
        ylabels = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

        # note I could have used nba_sort.columns but made "labels" instead
        ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels, minor=False)
        ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, minor=False)

        # rotate the
        #plt.xticks(rotation=90)

        ax.grid(False)

        # Turn off all the ticks
        ax = plt.gca()

        for t in ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
            t.tick1On = False
            t.tick2On = False
        for t in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
            t.tick1On = False
            t.tick2On = False

        plt.savefig('Group{}.png'.format(group), dpi=300, facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, format='png', transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')
```

The only limit/min/max/range I've found is for the color ramp (clim) and the Z values (vmin/vmax).

EDIT:  Tried using `ax.set_xlim()`, but it didn't work:
[image]

Comment: @ScottBoston, doesn't really help if you don't tell me what you think I did wrong...

Answer (score 3):

#### The problem

It's hard to tell the plotting function to plot some data which are simply not there. How should matplotlib know that there are values missing?

Let's consider this example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(6)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=31
hours = np.random.randint(1,13,size=n)
days = np.random.choice(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Fri','Sat','Sun'], size=n)
value = np.random.poisson(size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday' : days, 'Hour':hours, 'Value':value})
print (df)

piv = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Weekday', columns='Hour', values='Value')
piv = piv.fillna(0)
print(piv)
```

which produces the following pivot table, where Thursday as well as 8o'clock are missing.

```
Hour      1    2    3    4         5    6    7    9    10   11   12
Weekday                                                            
Fri      0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.666667  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
Mon      0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
Sat      1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Sun      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.5
Tue      0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Wed      0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.5  1.5  0.0
```

plotting this,

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 7])
heatmap = ax.pcolormesh(piv, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha=1)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(piv.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(piv.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(piv.columns, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(piv.index, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

produces the plot without the missing values, which is undesired, but clearly understandable, since they are not in the dataframe and hence not known to the plotting function.

[image]

#### A solution

A solution can be to create another dataframe full of `NaN`s, which actually has all the indices and columns in it that we later want to plot and update this dataframe with the pivot table we created from the data.

```
alldays = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
allhours = np.arange(1,13)
# Full dataframe with NaNs
full = pd.DataFrame(columns=allhours, index=alldays)
# pivot from data
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Weekday', columns='Hour', values='Value')
# fill full dataframe with pivot values
full.update(piv)
piv = full
piv = piv.fillna(0)
print(piv)
```

gives the following pivot table, which has zeroes in the 8o'clock column and the Thursday row.

```
      1    2    3    4         5    6    7   8    9    10   11   12
Mon  0.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  0.0   0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
Tue  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  1.0   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Wed  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0   0  2.0  1.5  1.5  0.0
Thu  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Fri  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.666667  0.0  0.0   0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
Sat  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  1.0  0.0   0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Sun  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.000000  0.0  0.0   0  0.0  0.0  1.0  2.5
```

Plotting this will then result in the desired plot

[image]

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(6)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n=31
hours = np.random.randint(1,13,size=n)
days = np.random.choice(['Mon','Tue','Wed','Fri','Sat','Sun'], size=n)
value = np.random.poisson(size=n)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weekday' : days, 'Hour':hours, 'Value':value})
print (df)

alldays = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
allhours = np.arange(1,13)
full = pd.DataFrame(columns=allhours, index=alldays)
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Weekday', columns='Hour', values='Value')
full.update(piv)
piv = full
piv = piv.fillna(0)
print(piv)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 7])
heatmap = ax.pcolormesh(piv, cmap=plt.cm.Reds, alpha=1)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(piv.shape[0]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(piv.shape[1]) + 0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(piv.columns, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(piv.index, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()` let you adjust axis bounds in matplotlib.

Comment: tried it with `ax.set_xlim(0,24)`, but it didn't work, other than flipping my y-axis... oops... See my edit for a picture.

Comment: This answer is not very constructive. Simply setting some limits on the axes will not help showing the data that isn't there. It will just create a lot of white space.